# Docker machine copying all of the host machine files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm fairly new to docker, but I recently discovered something that I just can't wrap my head around. I started a docker machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox machine_name
```

Created a docker-compose file for my application:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - '3007:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - project
    links:
      - project

  db:
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: ./services/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  project:
    container_name: project
    build: ./services/project
    volumes:
      - './services/project:/usr/src/app'
      - './services/project/package.json:/usr/src/app/package.json'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/esports_manager_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/esports_manager_test
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
      - TOKEN_SECRET=tempsectre
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

and then I ssh'd into the docker machine to find my entire filesystem. Is this intended behaviour, I can't seem to find anything in the docs that talks about it.

Comment: What do you mean by you found "your entire filesystem"? A docker image often contains an operating system image, which may look really similar to what's installed on your host.  You are *explicitly* exposing certain directories from your host filesystem through the use of the `volumes` key in each service.

Comment: larsks, sorry it took a while to respond. For example if I ssh into the docker machine, cd to the root of the machine, and go to users, my personal account is there. If I cd into that directory, I can find my Documents, all my personal Pictures, etc from my local machine.